# How to highlight newly added row to Vaadin table in different color on click of a button?

Tags: vaadin

I am new to Vaadin. How to highlight newly added row to Vaadin table in different color on click of a button? Below is the working code which is adding a new line to vaadin table on click of add button, but not highlighting in different colour. Here I have used DefaultFieldFactory to generate fields for each row.

```
public class ReviewTimesheetTable extends ViewComponent {

private Map<ReviewTimesheetTableDto, HashMap<String, AbstractField<?>>> 
tableItem = new HashMap<ReviewTimesheetTableDto, HashMap<String, 
AbstractField<?>>>();
BeanItemContainer<ReviewTimesheetTableDto> data = new 
BeanItemContainer<ReviewTimesheetTableDto>(
    ReviewTimesheetTableDto.class);
private Table table;
private Button btnAdd;

public void init() {
    btnAdd = new Button();
    btnAdd.setStyleName("link");
    btnAdd.setIcon(new ThemeResource("images/addbtn.png"));
    btnAdd.setDescription("Add Additional Task");

    VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();

// Create a data source and bind it to a table
table = new Table("", data);
table.addStyleName("generateColumnTable");
table.setWidth("100%");
table.setPageLength(table.getItemIds().size());
table.setVisibleColumns(new Object[] { "chkBox", "taskDate", "employeeId", "taskId", "crJiraId",
        "taskDesc","hour","minute"/*, "Delete" */});

table.setColumnHeader("chkBox", "Select");
table.setColumnHeader("taskDate", "Task Date");
table.setColumnHeader("employeeId", "Employee ID");
table.setColumnHeader("taskId", "Task ID");
table.setColumnHeader("crJiraId", "Subtask ID");
table.setColumnHeader("taskDesc", "Task Description");
table.setColumnHeader("hour", "Hour");
table.setColumnHeader("minute", "Minute");

table.setEditable(true);

table.setTableFieldFactory(new ImmediateFieldFactory());
    table.setWidth("200%");
    table.setPageLength(table.getItemIds().size());
    HorizontalLayout btnLayout = new HorizontalLayout(table, btnAdd);
    btnLayout.setWidth("100%");
    btnLayout.setComponentAlignment(btnAdd, Alignment.TOP_RIGHT);
    addListener();

    layout.setMargin(true);

    setCompositionRoot(btnLayout);

}

private void addListener() {
    btnAdd.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            ReviewTimesheetTableDto tableDTO = new ReviewTimesheetTableDto(createdBy);
            BeanItem<ReviewTimesheetTableDto> addItem = data.addItemAt(0,tableDTO);
        }
    });
}

public class ImmediateFieldFactory extends DefaultFieldFactory {

@Override
public Field<?> createField(Container container, Object itemId,
        Object propertyId, Component uiContext) {
    final ReviewTimesheetTableDto timesheetDetail = (ReviewTimesheetTableDto) itemId;

    Map<String, AbstractField<?>> tableRow = null;

    if(tableItem.get(timesheetDetail) == null)
    {
        tableItem.put(timesheetDetail,
                new HashMap<String, AbstractField<?>>());

    }
    tableRow = tableItem.get(timesheetDetail);

    if ("taskId".equals(propertyId)) {
        GComboBox box = new GComboBox();
        tableRow.put("taskId", box);
        setTaskValues(box, timesheetDetail);
        //addTaskListener(box);
        box.setData(timesheetDetail);
        if(timesheetDetail != null && timesheetDetail.getTaskId() != null) {
            box.setDescription(timesheetDetail.getTaskId().getValue());
        }
        if(isSubmit){
            box.setReadOnly(true);
        }

        if(timesheetDetail.getIsAdd() != null && timesheetDetail.getIsAdd()){
            box.setReadOnly(false);
        }
        return box;
    }else if ("crJiraId".equals(propertyId)) {
        TextField field = new TextField();
        field.setEnabled(true);
        field.setWidth("200px");
        field.setNullRepresentation("");
        if(isSubmit){
            field.setReadOnly(true);
        }
        if(timesheetDetail.getIsAdd() != null && timesheetDetail.getIsAdd()){
            field.setReadOnly(false);
        }
        field.setMaxLength(50);

        field.setDescription(timesheetDetail.getCrJiraId());
        tableRow.put("crJiraId", field);
        return field;
    }else if ("taskDesc".equals(propertyId)) {
        TextField field = new TextField();
        field.setEnabled(true);
        field.setWidth("300px");
        field.setNullRepresentation("");
        field.setReadOnly(false);
        tableRow.put("taskDesc", field);
        field.setMaxLength(2000);
        field.setData(timesheetDetail);
        addDetailPopupForTaskDesc(field, null);

        if(timesheetDetail.getTaskDesc() != null){
            field.setDescription(timesheetDetail.getTaskDesc());
        }
        field.setReadOnly(true);
        if(timesheetDetail.getIsAdd() != null && timesheetDetail.getIsAdd()){
            field.setReadOnly(false);
        }
        return field;
    }else if ("hour".equals(propertyId)) {
        GComboBox box = new GComboBox();
        box.setWidth("60px");
        tableRow.put("hour", box);
        box.addValueChangeListener(addHourListener(box));
        setHourValues(box, timesheetDetail);
        box.setData(timesheetDetail);
        if(isSubmit){
            box.setReadOnly(true);
        }
        if(timesheetDetail.getIsAdd() != null && timesheetDetail.getIsAdd()){
            box.setReadOnly(false);
        }
        return box;
    }else if ("minute".equals(propertyId)) {
        GComboBox box = new GComboBox();
        box.setWidth("80px");
        tableRow.put("minute", box);
        box.addValueChangeListener(addMinuteListener(box));
        setMinuteValues(box, timesheetDetail);
        box.setData(timesheetDetail);
        if(isSubmit){
            box.setReadOnly(true);
        }
        if(timesheetDetail.getIsAdd() != null && timesheetDetail.getIsAdd()){
            box.setReadOnly(false);
        }
        return box;
    }else if ("employeeId".equals(propertyId)) {
        /*TextField field = new TextField();
        field.setEnabled(true);
        field.setWidth("100%");
        field.setNullRepresentation("");
        field.setReadOnly(true);
        field.setMaxLength(50);
        field.setDescription(timesheetDetail.getEmpId());
        tableRow.put("empId", field);
        return field;*/

        GComboBox box = new GComboBox();
        tableRow.put("employeeId", box);
        setEmpValues(box, timesheetDetail);
        box.setData(timesheetDetail);
        if(timesheetDetail != null && timesheetDetail.getEmployeeId() != null) {
            box.setDescription(timesheetDetail.getEmployeeId().getValue());
        }
        if(isSubmit){
            box.setReadOnly(true);
        }
        if(timesheetDetail.getIsAdd() != null && timesheetDetail.getIsAdd()){
            box.setReadOnly(false);
        }
        /*if(timesheetDetail.getIsAdd() != null && timesheetDetail.getIsAdd()){
            box.setReadOnly(false);
        }*/
        return box;
    }else if ("taskDate".equals(propertyId)) {
        DateField field = new DateField();
        field.setEnabled(true);
        field.setWidth("110px");
        field.setReadOnly(true);
        if(timesheetDetail.getIsAdd() != null && timesheetDetail.getIsAdd()){
            field.setReadOnly(false);
        }
        field.setDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

        tableRow.put("taskDate", field);
        return field;
    }else if ("chkBox".equals(propertyId)) {
        CheckBox field = new CheckBox();
        field.setEnabled(true);
        field.setWidth("30px");
        field.setDescription(SHAConstants.SELECT);
        tableRow.put("chkBox", field);
        return field;
    }else {
        Field<?> field = super.createField(container, itemId,
                propertyId, uiContext);

        if (field instanceof TextField)
            field.setWidth("100%");
        field.setEnabled(true);
        return field;
    }
}
}


/*POJO (Bean)*/
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import com.shaic.arch.fields.dto.SelectValue;
import com.shaic.arch.table.AbstractTableDTO;
import com.vaadin.data.util.BeanItemContainer;

public class ReviewTimesheetTableDto extends AbstractTableDTO  implements Serializable {


@NotNull(message = "Please Select Task ID")
private SelectValue taskId;
@NotNull(message = "Please Enter Hours")
private SelectValue hour;
@NotNull(message = "Please Enter Minutes")
private SelectValue minute;

private BeanItemContainer<SelectValue> taskIdList;
private BeanItemContainer<SelectValue> hourList;
private BeanItemContainer<SelectValue> minuteList;

@NotNull(message = "Please Enter Sub Task")
@Size (min =1, message="Please Enter Sub Task")
private String crJiraId;

private String taskDesc;

@NotNull(message = "Please Enter Task Date")
private Date taskDate;

private Long key;

private Long hourValue;

private Long minuteValue;

private String createdBy;

//private String empId;

private Boolean chkBox;

@NotNull(message = "Please Select Employee ID")
private SelectValue employeeId;

public ReviewTimesheetTableDto() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public ReviewTimesheetTableDto(String createdBy) {
    super();
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
    this.isAdd = Boolean.TRUE;
}

public ReviewTimesheetTableDto(Date taskDate, String userName, String createdBy) {
    super();
    this.taskDate = taskDate;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.isAdd = Boolean.TRUE;
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
}

private Boolean isSubmit;

private Boolean isAdd;

private String userName;

public SelectValue getTaskId() {
    return taskId;
}

public void setTaskId(SelectValue taskId) {
    this.taskId = taskId;
}

public BeanItemContainer<SelectValue> getTaskIdList() {
    return taskIdList;
}

public void setTaskIdList(BeanItemContainer<SelectValue> taskIdList) {
    this.taskIdList = taskIdList;
}

public String getCrJiraId() {
    return crJiraId;
}

public void setCrJiraId(String crJiraId) {
    this.crJiraId = crJiraId;
}

public String getTaskDesc() {
    return taskDesc;
}

public void setTaskDesc(String taskDesc) {
    this.taskDesc = taskDesc;
}

public SelectValue getHour() {
    return hour;
}

public void setHour(SelectValue hour) {
    this.hour = hour;
}

public SelectValue getMinute() {
    return minute;
}

public void setMinute(SelectValue minute) {
    this.minute = minute;
}

public BeanItemContainer<SelectValue> getHourList() {
    return hourList;
}

public void setHourList(BeanItemContainer<SelectValue> hourList) {
    this.hourList = hourList;
}

public BeanItemContainer<SelectValue> getMinuteList() {
    return minuteList;
}

public void setMinuteList(BeanItemContainer<SelectValue> minuteList) {
    this.minuteList = minuteList;
}

public Long getKey() {
    return key;
}

public void setKey(Long key) {
    this.key = key;
}

public Long getHourValue() {
    return hourValue;
}

public void setHourValue(Long hourValue) {
    this.hourValue = hourValue;
}

public Long getMinuteValue() {
    return minuteValue;
}

public void setMinuteValue(Long minuteValue) {
    this.minuteValue = minuteValue;
}

public Boolean getIsSubmit() {
    return isSubmit;
}

public void setIsSubmit(Boolean isSubmit) {
    this.isSubmit = isSubmit;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public Date getTaskDate() {
    return taskDate;
}

public void setTaskDate(Date taskDate) {
    this.taskDate = taskDate;
}

public Boolean getIsAdd() {
    return isAdd;
}

public void setIsAdd(Boolean isAdd) {
    this.isAdd = isAdd;
}

public String getCreatedBy() {
    return createdBy;
}

public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
}

/*public String getEmpId() {
    return empId;
}

public void setEmpId(String empId) {
    this.empId = empId;
}*/

public Boolean getChkBox() {
    return chkBox;
}

public void setChkBox(Boolean chkBox) {
    this.chkBox = chkBox;
}

public SelectValue getEmployeeId() {
    return employeeId;
}

public void setEmployeeId(SelectValue employeeId) {
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
}

}
```

Output of above code:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to use https://vaadin.com/api/7.7.13/com/vaadin/ui/Table.CellStyleGenerator.html to define conditional style name for the highlight. There are couple of options. If your item has date property which is set when updated, you could do comparison with that date and highlight rows that have been added in certain time frame, to indicate these are new. Alternatively you could have timer process clearing highlights after being added.

Comment: I don't think this works if you want to change the style on the fly - CellStyleGenerator does not get called if you, say, have have an action handler to change a color based on right click.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: never mind.  Key was table.refreshRowCache() inside my handle action.  That updated table CSS.  Now if I can just get the browsers to actually use the new CSS class I added.